# NPAPI: Finer control with NPN_RequestRead

Tags: firefox, mozilla, npapi

I am trying to build an [NPAPI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/tag/NPAPI) which will download portion of the stream on an on-demand basis. I have been making progress ([compared to previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24514909/npapi-basic-usage-of-npn-requestread)). I now have:

```
int32_t NPP_WriteReady(NPP instance, NPStream* stream)
{
  NPByteRange range;
  range.offset = 0;
  range.length = 300; // at least a non-null size request
  range.next = NULL;
  NPError e = s_pBrowserFunctions->requestread(stream,&range));
  return 0;
}
```

which seems to be going in the right direction. I can see in the [Network History](http://www.botskool.com/geeks/network-tools-monitor-internet-data-usage-ubuntu-1010) (System Monitor) that the plugin is downloading a couple of Mbytes and then finally stops.

What I would like now is be able to have a finer control of this 'inertia'. I cannot call [NPN_RequestRead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/NPN_RequestRead) from [NPP_NewStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/NPP_NewStream) because it is too early and returns an error. I cannot call NPN_RequestRead from [NPP_Write](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/NPP_Write) because it seems to be too late. And calling NPN_RequestRead from [NPP_WriteReady](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/NPP_WriteReady) still download a couple too much stuff which I'd be happy to skip.

How do I make sure to only download the minimal stuff before the very first call to [NPN_RequestRead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/NPN_RequestRead) ?

Comment: It may not be possible with this API; you might be better off getting the proxy information from the browser and using something else, such as curl